# How to write loop so that cipherkey can be greater than 26?

Tags: python-3.x

I need the cipher key to be able to be infinitely bigger than just the size of the alphabet (26) but still have a final key between 1-26

I am thinking about something like this:

```
if cipherKey > 26 and :
    cipherKey = cipherKey - 26
```

But I think using a for loop to add the infinitely bigger condition so that if the cipher ends up being infinite + 26 the key will just be 26.
For example if the key is 30, then the cipher key is just 4.

Comment: Instead of using loop and minus why don't you use arithmetic operation like "division"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution

```
cipherKey = cipherKey%26
```

Comment: @Alexander Richmond, please let me know if this helped